# JavaScript .checked on radio buttons acting odd

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to force a user to select a radio option on a page, but when the user checks the 'No' option, my .checked value is coming up `false`.

```
var long = document.getElementById('long');

if(long.checked == false){
  message += '- Please select your stance\\r\\n';
  errors = true;
}

<input name='long' id='long' type='radio' value='Yes' >Yes 
<input name='long' id='long' type='radio' value='No' >No
```

Comment: please give a http://jsfiddle.net/ example show what is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your inputs have an id of "long", so getElementById is probably returning the first one, which is the "Yes" button.

Answer (score 1):

You can't give two elements the same "id" value. You could use `.getElementsByName()` to find the set of radio buttons, and then look for the one that's checked, or give them two different "id" values (which is what I'd probably do).

```
<input name='long' id='long_yes' type='radio' value='Yes'>Yes
<input name='long' id='long_no' type='radio' value='No'>No
```

Answer (score 1):

IDs must be unique, according to the HTML spec, therefore your code will not work as written.

If you look at it from a FORM approach, the radio buttons are an array:

```
var radios = document.form1.long
for(var x=0;x<radios.length;x++) {
     alert(radios[x].value)
}
```

So you can check if YES is selected like this because YES is the first element in the array.

```
var radios = document.form1.long
if(radios[0].checked) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two checkboxes with the same ID property. Give them each a different ID and it should work properly.

```
var long            = document.getElementById('longNo');

if(long.checked == false){
    message += '- Please select your stance\\r\\n';
    errors = true;
}


  <input name='long' id='longYes' type='radio' value='Yes' >Yes 
  <input name='long'  id='longNo' type='radio' value='No' >No
```

Answer (score 0):

Both radio buttons have the same ID so it is only getting the first one from the getElementById call.

Change your code to use `document.getElementsByName("long")` then loop over and check each one:

```
var long = document.getElementsByName('long'), message = "";
var checked = false;
for (var i = 0; i < long.length; i++) {
    if (long[i].checked) {
        checked = true;
    }
}

if(!checked){
    message += '- Please select your stance\\r\\n';
    alert(message);
}
```

With none checked - http://jsfiddle.net/myFhm/
With no checked - http://jsfiddle.net/myFhm/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have the same id for both radio buttons, the names need to stay the same but they must have different ids

Try this:

```
var longYes            = document.getElementById('longYes');
var longNo            = document.getElementById('longNo');

if(longYes.checked == false && longNo.checked == false){
    message += '- Please select your stance\\r\\n';
    errors = true;
}


  <input name='long' id='longYes' type='radio' value='Yes' >Yes 
  <input name='long'  id='longNo' type='radio' value='No' >No
```